# Можно создать конструктор в JS, в который можно предавать произвольное количество параметров?

Tags: javascript, класс

Пробую сделать в таком духе:

```
class Car {
  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      let property = `property ${i}`;
      this.property = arguments[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Хочу чтобы при создании обьектов я мог передавать произвольное количество параметров конструктору.

свойства обьекта выглядили таким образом:

```
{property1 : мой параметр 1,
property2 : мой параметр 2,
property3 : мой параметр 3,
property4 : мой параметр 4}
…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let property = `property${i + 1}`;
this[property] = arguments[i];
```

Comment: со скобками заработало, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

```js
class Car {
  constructor(...wheels) {
    let count = 0
    for (let wheel of wheels) {
      this[`wheel${++count}`] = wheel
    }
  }
  calculate() {
    console.log(
      Array.prototype.reduce.call(Object.entries(this), (a, [p,v]) => {
        if (/^wheel/.test(p)) {
          a += `Колесо: ${v}\n`
        }
        return a
      }, '')
    )
  }
}

let arrWheels = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 'запаска'
]

let car = new Car(...arrWheels)
car.calculate()
```

Comment: спасибо, но думаю сделать с псевдомассивом "arguments".
Нужно было доставить только [ ] после this чтобы заработало.

Comment: @Aleksey да не за что :). Последние аргументы по мне предпочтительнее. Тем более все бандлеры без проблем переводят это в "старый" код с arguments.